# How do I pass lookup object values into a FetchXml query?

Tags: javascript, object, dynamics-crm-2015, fetchxml, lookupfield

I am trying to filter a lookup field `products` with another lookup field `editorial` (my company sells textbooks).

I know how to retrieve values from the lookup object but I do not know how to pass them into my fetchXml query statement.

```
function preFilterLookup()
{
    Xrm.Page.getControl("new_editorialsearch").addPreSearch(function () { 

        var ediObject = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_editorialsearch").getValue();

        // Get the lookup Object, and extract the Value (ID and Text)
        if(ediObject != null)
        {
            var ediTextValue = ediObject[0].name;
            var ediID = ediObject[0].id;

            // Filter products by editorial
            fetchXml = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='name' operator='eq' value='" + ediTextValue + "' /></filter>";

            // Apply the filter to the field
            Xrm.Page.getControl("new_engpro").addCustomFilter(fetchXml);
        }        
    });
}
```

I know I'm doing something wrong because CRM keeps telling me my function is undefined, and I can't see any syntax errors.

Can somebody please tell me the proper way to pass the object name and id into the fetchXml statement?

Comment: If you're getting a function is undefined error, it's probably not an issue with the fetch but rather an issue with how you're calling `preFilterLookup`. Put in a `console.log("running");` statement at the beginning of your function to make sure it is actually executing.  If that doesn't get you over the hump, please provide the error message you're getting and also let us know how you're wiring up the event.

Comment: Originally it was 'onLoad' but I set it to 'onChange' for 'editorial' and it doesnt give me an error, but it doesn't do what I want either. 'console.log("running")' displays **running** so the function is happening. Is my 'fetchXml' correct? Am I passing the data correctly?

Comment: I no longer get the error 'onLoad' but it isn't filtering. I put a log statement inside the 'if' statement and it's not displaying anything. The 'if' statement seems to be returning 'null' even though the field has a value. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`addCustomFilter` can only be called from the `addPreSearch` event of the same control.  So instead of calling `addPreSearch` on `new_editorialsearch`, call it on `new_engpro`.